# Elastic synonyms are taking over other words

Tags: elasticsearch

On this sequence of commands:

Create the index:

```
PUT /test_index?
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "GermanCompoundWordsAnalyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "german_compound_synonym",
            "german_normalization"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "german_compound_synonym": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "teppichläufer, auslegware läufer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text", 
          "analyzer": "GermanCompoundWordsAnalyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Adding a few documents:

```
POST test_index/_doc/
{
    "sku" : "kimchy",
    "name" : "teppichläufer alfa"
}

POST test_index/_doc/
{
    "sku" : "kimchy",
    "name" : "teppichläufer beta"
}
```

Search for one document (I would expect), but 2 are returning :(

```
GET /test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "teppichläufer beta",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I will get both documents since the synonym `teppichläufer, auslegware läufer`, `läufer` will endup on the position 1 and 'substitute' the `beta`. If I remove the `"analyzer": "GermanCompoundWordsAnalyzer"`, I will just get one document as expected.

How do I use this synonyms and don't have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
   "bool" : {
        "should": [
          {
            "query_string": {
              "default_field": "name",
              "query": "teppichläufer beta"
              , "default_operator": "AND"
            }
          }
          ]
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you please tell you still getting 2 or as expect

Comment: Nothing changes, I continue getting the 2 answers.

Comment: can you share your mapping and some data sample so i can test on hand and help properly

Comment: You have that on the question.
The schema, adding 2 documents and my query

Answer (score 0):

After a little more search I found it on the documentations. This a RFM problems, sorry guys.

I tried with:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/analysis-synonym-graph-tokenfilter.html

The funny part is that it makes the NDCG of the results worst :)